# Create permutations of a nested dict

Tags: python

I'm writing a code that should go over reg_lines and create all the permutations for (1) which lines to use with each protocol and (2) what lines to disconnect in order to check some functionality.

```
reg_lines = {'primary': ['ETH', 'UDP', 'TCP'], 'secondary': ['ETH', 'TCP'], 'private': ['UDP', 'TCP']}
```

Expected permutations:

1.

```
use = [{'primary':'ETH'}]
disc = [{'primary':'ETH'}]
```

2. 

```
use = [{'primary': 'TCP'}]
disc = [{'primary': 'TCP'}]
```

...

j.

```
use = [{'secondary': 'TCP'}]
disc = [{'secondary': 'TCP'}]
```

...

i.

```
use = [{'primary': 'ETH', 'secondary': 'ETH'}
disc = [{'primary': 'ETH'}]
```

i+1.

```
use = [{'primary': 'ETH', 'secondary': 'ETH'}]
disc = [{'primary': 'ETH'}]
```

i+2.

```
use = [{'primary': 'ETH', 'secondary': 'ETH'}]
disc = [{'primary': 'ETH', 'secondary': 'ETH'}]
```

...

n.

```
use = [{'primary': 'TCP', 'secondary': 'TCP', 'private': 'TCP'}]
disc = [{'primary': 'TCP', 'secondary': 'TCP', 'private': 'TCP'}]
```

Comment: Tried to play with itertools.combinations, but I come up with something really messy.

Comment: To me problem is not clear where is `priv_lines` since given `reg_lines`

Comment: @SIslam, you are correct. I simplified the question. Removed priv_lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `itertools.combinations` to get all the combinations of primary, secondary, and private, and then `itertools.product` to get the product of those. Then use `itertools.combinations` again to get all the subsets of those for the `disc` dictionaries.

```
from itertools import product, combinations, chain

reg_lines = {'primary': ['ETH', 'UDP', 'TCP'], 'secondary': ['ETH', 'TCP'], 'private': ['UDP', 'TCP']}

def all_combinations(lst):
    return chain(*[combinations(lst, i+1) for i in range(len(lst))])

for comb in all_combinations(reg_lines):
    for prod in product(*(reg_lines[k] for k in comb)):
        use = dict(zip(comb, prod))
        print("use", use)
        for comb2 in all_combinations(comb):
            disc = {k: use[k] for k in comb2}
            print("disc", disc)
```

Output:

```
use {'primary': 'ETH'}
disc {'primary': 'ETH'}
use {'primary': 'UDP'}
disc {'primary': 'UDP'}
... many many more ...
use {'primary': 'TCP', 'secondary': 'TCP', 'private': 'TCP'}
disc {'primary': 'TCP'}
disc {'secondary': 'TCP'}
disc {'private': 'TCP'}
disc {'primary': 'TCP', 'secondary': 'TCP'}
disc {'primary': 'TCP', 'private': 'TCP'}
disc {'secondary': 'TCP', 'private': 'TCP'}
disc {'primary': 'TCP', 'secondary': 'TCP', 'private': 'TCP'}
```

Comment: In your example you don't get permutations for only 'secondary' or 'secondary' + 'private' (use = dict(zip(("primary", "secondary", "private"), x)))

Comment: @alnet Yes, that part was a bit unclear in the question IMHO. How about now?